# Django print choices value

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

```
EMP_CHOICES = (
         (0,'-- Select --'),
         (1,'Good'),
         (2,'Average'),
     )

class EMPFeedback(models.Model):
     user_choices = models.IntegerField(choices=EMP_CHOICES)
```

If the value stored in the db as 1 for user_choices how to print the corresponding user_choices corresponding value (i.e. 1==GOOD)

```
fb = EMPFeedback.objects.get(id=1)
print fb.user_choices  # prints 1
print fb.user_choices.EMP_CHOICES
```

Answer (score 119, accepted):

There's a [method](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.get_FOO_display) for that! (™ Apple)

```
fb.get_user_choices_display()
```

Comment: To get the value in the template: `{{ fb.get_user_choices_display }}`

Comment: how can i get key of choices field in template? i want to get key but when i write: {{obj.x }} the same as {{obj.get_x_display}} why?