# Django/Python: How to cast an integer into the equivalent enum string?

Tags: python, django

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Django print choices value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4274243/django-print-choices-value)

In Django in one of the models I have the following enum:

```
PRIORITY = (
        ('2',     _(u'High')),
        ('1',   _(u'Medium')),
        ('0',      _(u'Low')),
    )

priority = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=PRIORITY, default='1')
```

When sending the priority to the template, the value is still in integer, which isn't nice. I would like to show the priority in words rather than digits.

```
context = Context({'priority':self.priority})
```

Is there a way to translate priority into the actual string without using any if statements before sending it to the template?

Comment: Technically, `'1'` is a string and not an integer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, according to [the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.get_FOO_display) you can get the human readable value like this:

```
context.get_priority_display()
```

Answer (score -2):

The value on the left is the value Django uses to store in the db. It doesn't have to be an integer. Just make both values identical:

```
PRIORITY = (
        ('high',     _(u'High')),
        ('Medium',   _(u'Medium')),
        ('Low',      _(u'Low')),
    )
```