# Best way to get at Human Text from stored code in dictionary in Django

Tags: python, database, django

I'm storing multiple choices via checkboxes in a table and want to return the human readable part of the choice.

```
CHOICES = (
      ('_NN', 'Choice 1'),
      ('_GK', 'Choice 2'),
      ('_SA', ''),
      ('_ES', ''),
      ('_SH', ''),
      ('_CU', ''),
      ('_EN', '...'),
)
```

So the object model is returning say "_NN", what is the smartest way of returning "Choice 1", given that I have both the CHOICES and these Choices located in a table. I'm trying to avoid looking up in the db - is there a smart way to do it?

Comment: do you need `dict(CHOICES)['_NN']`?

Comment: In the model is the field supplied the choices parameter? If so: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4274243/django-print-choices-value then you can use that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Django `Model` class provides you with a [`get_FOO_display()` method](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.get_FOO_display), designed precisely to do that.

Comment: Thanks - didn't know that existed. Works well for my fields apart from ManyToManyFields - any ideas how to make these work?