# Django Choices Reference in View

Tags: python, django, typeerror, python-docx

Model.py:

```
class RiskIssue(models.Model):
RISK_ISSUE_SEVERITY = (
    ('L', 'Low'),
    ('M', 'Medium'),
    ('H', 'High'),
)
projectRiskIssueSeverity = models.CharField("Risk/Issue Severity", max_length=1, choices=RISK_ISSUE_SEVERITY, default='L')
```

View.py code:

```
cell = table.rows[2].cells[0]
formatted_status = [astatus.get_risk_issue_severity_display() for astatus in activitylist.values_list('activityStatus', flat=True)]
cell.paragraphs[0].text = ', '.join(formatted_status)
```

I am getting the error code: 'unicode' object has no attribute 'get_risk_issue_severity_display'

What am I doing wrong? I have tried everything except the correct answer. 
Very small TypeError problem here I assume

Comment: Where is get_risk_issue_severity_display()  defined?

Comment: so i was going off this other post, i thought it was defined in django. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4274243/django-print-choices-value

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.get_FOO_display
This document is from the question in your comment.

it should be Model.get_FOO_display()
where FOO is fieldname your field name seems wrong.

Comment: Did you miss 'objects'? activitylist.objects.values_list('activityStatus', flat=True)

Comment: activitylist is a unicode object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use get_FOO_display() with a string value as you are trying to do. You would need an instance of the model for it to work. As you have it, what your code is translating to is something like:

```
'L'.get_projectRiskIssueSeverity_display()
```

That's where the "no attribute" error comes from.

If you just want a list of the possible values you would be better off using `RiskIssue.RISK_ISSUE_SEVERITY` directly from the view and transforming it to a list or whatever you need.

Answer (score 1):

Model.get_FOO_display() in the documentation says should have FOO as the field name as FOO in your case field name is projectRiskIssueSeverity not risk_issue_severity.

and objects seems to be missing from the activitylist.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.get_FOO_display

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.values_list

Comment: that makes sense, however I am still receiving this error: 'unicode' object has no attribute 'get_projectRiskIssueSeverity_display'

Comment: astatus is a unicode object from my valuelistqueryset. If i just put that into the paragraph text, it comes out at "M" and not "Medium"

Comment: also, when I add objects to the activity list, i get the error: 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'objects'

I know this is correct because i implemented that later with formatted_dates = [date.strftime("%B %d,%Y") for date in activitylist.values_list('activityPlannedStartDate', flat=True)]
 cell.paragraphs[0].text = ', '.join(formatted_dates)
and it worked.